# Java: Writing multiple int arrays to a binary file for inverted index

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently doing a inverted index project in Java that will write arrays of int to a binary file and then save the offsets and how much bytes to read for each array, so it can be read back into memory later on. How will I be able to do that? I have never dealt with binary files before, so I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: You begin by reading the documentation. `DataOutputStream` or `RandomAccesFile` spring to mind immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can write raw data with [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and read it with [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). This guarantees that the data is not written as text.

These two classes have basically one overload for each of the primitive type such as `int`, `float`, `char`, etc, which makes it pretty straight forward to use them. To write and read `int`s you have the methods `writeInt()` and `readInt()`.

As an example you could write your `int[]` like so:

```
int[] myArray = ...;
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\somefile.dat"));

//write the length first so that you can later know how many ints to read
os.writeInt(myArray.length);
for (int i =0 ; i < myArray.length; ++i){
    os.writeInt(myArray[i]);
}

os.close();
```

And to read it back:

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\somefile.dat"));

int size = is.readInt(); //read the size which is the first int
int[] myArray = new int[size]; //use it to reconstruct the array

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    myArray[i] = is.readInt(); //read all the remaining ints
}

is.close();
```

Note that these examples had no exception handling, which is important if you want to make sure your program doesn't crash in cases where the file doesn't exist or the data is corrupted.